# Can I set log level for appender wider than respective logger ?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have the following log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, myappender, console

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=com.nasdaq.fbms.logging.custom.EscapedEnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS z} %-5p [%t] %c{1.}#%M:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.File=D:/folder/myLog.log
log4j.appender.myappender.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.myappender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.myappender.Threshold=ERROR
```

at this case I see only errors in `myLog.log`

but if I set `log4j.appender.myappender.Threshold=TRACE` - I see errors and warns, but don't see debug info and traces

Can I set log level for appender wider than respective logger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer no.

You need to set the appender's threshold to TRACE and the level of the logger to TRACE too.

Here, you don't have any logger defined, so it uses the rootLogger parameter value which is WARN.
If you change it to TRACE you should see more logs.

If you want to keep your rootLogger this way you can limit the level to a specific logger like this:

```
log4j.category.my.custom.logger=TRACE
```